# How to deploy Web Application in Tomcat7 using Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

Can any one tell how would I deploy my `Web Application` in `Tomcat7` using `Eclipse Indigo`. When I manually create `WAR` and paste it in `WebApps/ROOT` then it works. But in`Eclipse IDE`, server started successfully but not able to deploy `war/web application`. I also added my`Web Application using Add/Remove Server properties` but all in vain. Only `Apache server startUp` page shown. Also when I double click `Server` My `Server Locations` tab is disabled. I don't know WHY ?

Secondly by default `apache server access any jsp direct from WEBAPPS/abc.jsp or WEBAPPS/ROOT/abc.jsp`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `tomcat/web.xml` is not properly configured. Follow this steps to get it work -

1. First deleted server from servers tab in eclipse.
2. Then add new server from wizard - which will ask you to give path of your tomcat installation directory usually in - `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation`
3. While last step, you will prompt an dialog box listing all the open projects of eclipse, to be add in tomcat environment.
4. Click finish and clean/build project.
5. check in web.xml that, your welcome file is properly added.(usually under WebContent directory )

Hope this will work for you.

Also note that, While developing any application, you don't need to create WAR.

Comment: I did what you say but still my application not deployed in Tomcat Web Apps. I ran server but I have no URL from where I can access my Application.

Answer (score 0):

You right click on tomcat icon in server tab then click on properties. In general click on "Switch Location" button then apply and ok. Now double click on Tomcat icon and see your Server Location is now enable. Then click on second radio button and save. Then try again to deploy. It should work.